# emulator does not boot

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I am unable to get emulator to boot.  I am running opensuse 12.1, have the latest SDK (20.0.3) and have been working with the instructions at developer.android

I have tried to start the emulator two ways, eclipse and command line both with the same result, things look to start and then freeze.  eclipse will go through the motions but no devices appear when i check "adb devices" and eclipse does not find any devices.  if I check processes on the machine an emulator process appears but if left for hours it never materializes.

I installed/uninstalled several times.

Comment: For future reference, it helps to identify **what** emulator you're using, since there are many available. Specific information helps you get answers more quickly.

Comment: the emulator resides here: /android-sdk-linux/tools.  the instructions at http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html sound like unpack SDK run emulator.  everything else there does work (android, ddms, etc).

Comment: I was referring to the tags you applied to your question. You used only `emulator`, and your question title said `emulator does not boot`, neither of which said what kind of emulator (iOS, Android, etc.). I added the `Android` tag based on content, and provided advice for future questions. :-)

Comment: i made some progress.  I can load an emulator if I switch to the root user.  so the loading has to do with permissions, which I have not figured out yet.  also the emulator loads as "offline" need to figure that out as well.

Comment: fixed.  apparently a known bug code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34233 **removing or renaming tools/lib/libOpenglRender.so** fixed everything

Answer (score 0):

removing or renaming tools/lib/libOpenglRender.so

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34233